# Select the max,min value from another aggregate query

Tags: sql, oracle

Problem Statement: Want to select the `maximum` and `minimum` value from another aggregate result. The inside query (please check the query below) is giving me the count of `SERIES_INSTANCE_UID` per day & want to fetch the `max and min` value and corresponding `SERIES_INSTANCE_UID` for the max and min value. I am able to retrieve the max and min value but not able to fetch the associated `SERIES_INSTANCE_UID`. How to retrieve it ?

```
SELECT MIN("COUNT_SIU") FROM
(SELECT  TRUNC(CREATED_DATE),SERIES_INSTANCE_UID,COUNT(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID) AS "COUNT_SIU" FROM IMAGE_HISTORY
WHERE CREATED_DATE >= SYSDATE-1 GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATED_DATE),SERIES_INSTANCE_UID ORDER BY COUNT(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID) DESC)


SELECT MAX("COUNT_SIU") FROM
(SELECT  TRUNC(CREATED_DATE),SERIES_INSTANCE_UID,COUNT(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID) AS "COUNT_SIU" FROM IMAGE_HISTORY
WHERE CREATED_DATE >= SYSDATE-1 GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATED_DATE),SERIES_INSTANCE_UID ORDER BY COUNT(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID) DESC)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **minimum** version, include `rank` analytic function (which ranks rows by result of the `count` function) into subquery; then fetch row(s) that rank as the highest.

```
  SELECT count_siu, series_instance_uid
    FROM (  SELECT TRUNC (created_date),
                   series_instance_uid,
                   COUNT (series_instance_uid) AS count_siu,
                   RANK () OVER (ORDER BY COUNT (series_instance_uid)) rnk
              FROM image_history
             WHERE created_date >= SYSDATE - 1
          GROUP BY TRUNC (created_date), series_instance_uid)
   WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY series_instance_uid;
```

Do the same for the **maximum** version, only this time rank rows by count function's result in descending order; rest of query remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MIN(series_instance_uid) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY count_siu)` to get the minimum UID for the lowest count.

To get it all in one query:

```sql
SELECT MIN(COUNT_SIU) AS min_count,
       MIN(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY COUNT_SIU)
         AS min_uid_for_min_count,
       MAX(COUNT_SIU) AS max_count,
       MAX(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY COUNT_SIU)
         AS max_uid_for_max_count
FROM   (
  SELECT SERIES_INSTANCE_UID,
         COUNT(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID) AS COUNT_SIU
  FROM   IMAGE_HISTORY
  WHERE  CREATED_DATE >= SYSDATE-1
  GROUP BY TRUNC(CREATED_DATE),
         SERIES_INSTANCE_UID
)
```

or, without the sub-query:

```sql
SELECT MIN(COUNT(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID)) AS min_count,
       MIN(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID)
         KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY COUNT(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID))
         AS min_series_instance_uid,
       MAX(COUNT(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID)) AS max_count,
       MAX(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID)
         KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY COUNT(SERIES_INSTANCE_UID))
         AS max_series_instance_uid
FROM   IMAGE_HISTORY
WHERE  CREATED_DATE >= SYSDATE-1
GROUP BY
       TRUNC(CREATED_DATE),
       SERIES_INSTANCE_UID
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE image_history (created_date, series_instance_uid) AS
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND, 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 2 UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND, 2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' SECOND, 3 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 6 UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE), 1 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE), 2 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE), 3 FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 7;
```

Outputs:

| MIN_COUNT | MIN_SERIES_INSTANCE_UID | MAX_COUNT | MAX_SERIES_INSTANCE_UID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 7 | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/LCQOQ0lo)